# Proxmox Ceph OSD Fault

Tags: proxmox, ceph

I am running Proxmox with 2 nodes and Ceph. Recently I had a drive die and replaced it. In the process of trying to initialize it as an OSD, all I get are fault errors:

```
2017-07-31 15:05:05.278499 7fe2ac319700  0 -- :/2194139526 >> 172.18.1.4:6789/0 pipe(0x7fe2a805f1c0 sd=3 :0 s=1 pgs=0 cs=0 l=1 c=0x7fe2a805ceb0).fault
```

The syslog is full of lines like this:

```
Jul 31 15:03:01 thebrain ceph-osd-prestart.sh[2460]: 2017-07-31 15:03:01.817941 7f1258204700  0 -- :/2850968481 >> 172.18.1.4:6789/0 pipe(0x7f1248005160 sd=4 :0 s=1 pgs=0 cs=0 l=1 c=0x7f1248004050).fault
```

During this switch I also moved the monitors and ceph.conf from different addresses to a different subnet. Switching them back to the old addresses doesn't stop the errors, but maybe this has something to do with the errors.

Any advice on troubleshooting this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are two ceph.conf. Proxmox places one in /etc/pve and that is the one that is shown in the web interface. Ceph actually uses the one in /etc/ceph and these did not match. Changing the /etc/ceph one to match the /etc/pve one has solved the faults issue.